# Solve the Double qoutes within double quotes issue in R

Tags: r

With R, when we put double quotes inside a double quotes:

```
y <- " " " "
```

It will end out

> Error: unexpected string constant in "y <- " " " ""

My question is how to remove all the double quotes detected or convert into single quotes within the main double quotes.

For example:

```
y <- "I'm watching "Prometheus"." 
y
```

The desired result is

```
#[1] "I'm watching Prometheus."
```

or

```
#[1] "I'm watching 'Prometheus'."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you parsing string input from a file or standard input of something?

`scan(what='character',sep='\n')` will read data from the `stdin()` and automatically escape the quotes. Same if from a file

```
>scan(what="character",sep="\n",allowEscapes=T)
1: I'm watching "Prometheus"
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] "I'm watching \"Prometheus\""
>
>scan(what="character",sep="\n",allowEscapes=T)
1: "I'm watching "Prometheus""
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] "\"I'm watching \"Prometheus\"\""
```

Once you've got your input you could use a regular expression to replace the escaped inner quotes... (I think! - might be a complicated reg exp)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I'm looking for!
> y <- scan(what="character",sep="\n",allowEscapes=T)
I'm watching "Prometheus".

y

Answer (score 4):

Im probably not getting it but

```
gsub("\"","","I'm watching \"Prometheus\".")
```

or

```
gsub("\"","'","I'm watching \"Prometheus\".")
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
y <-  "I\'m watching 'Prometheus'."

[1] "I'm watching 'Prometheus'."

y <-  "I\'m watching Prometheus."

[1] "I'm watching Prometheus."
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of \ and single quotes around double quotes in a similar situation I had.

I wanted to pass the following string into a function as a test

> "count(grepl("[()']", df$var)==T)>0"

but the [()'] became unquoted, the solution was

> "count(grepl("'[()']'", df$var)==T)>0"