# How to print variables inside quotes in message()

Tags: r

I have the following variables:

```
min.v<-5
max.v<-10
```

and i want to message the following

```
Test this. You entered "5 10"
```

Is this possible to print this with `message()` or `paste()`, since both functions regard quotes as strings. **The variables in the message should be inside double quotes**

I have tried `message(as.character(paste(min.v, " ",max.v)))` but the double quotes are ignored.

This question is probably the exact opposite of this [Solve the Double qoutes within double quotes issue in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117321/solve-the-double-qoutes-within-double-quotes-issue-in-r)

Comment: It isn't so much that `paste` and `message` "regard quotes as strings" as it is that the R interpreter regards quotes as specifying object names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have <strike>two</strike> three options of doing this

Option 1: Escape the quotes. To do this, you have to use `\"`.

```
cat("You entered ", "\"", min.v, " ", max.v,"\"", sep="")
You entered "5 10"
```

Option 2: Embed your double quotes in single quotes:

```
cat("You entered ", '"', min.v, " ", max.v,'"', sep="")
You entered "5 10"
```

---

**Edit:** *with acknowledgement to @baptiste, in an effort to make this answer comprehensive*

Option3: Use the function `dQuote()`:

```
options(useFancyQuotes=FALSE)
cat("You entered ", dQuote(paste(min.v, max.v)), sep="")
You entered "5 10"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
x = 5; y = "indeed"
message("you entered ", dQuote(x))
message("you entered ", dQuote(paste(x, y)))
```

Comment: @GSee you need to concatenate them first

Answer (score 0):

Although `sprintf` can get quite complex, I find the code is generally neater than most other options. Essentially, you have a message that you want to format where you want to insert variable values -- this is what `sprintf` is for:

```
min.v <- 5
max.v <- 10
msg <- 'Test this. You entered "%i %i"\n'
str <- sprintf(msg, min.v, max.v) #generates string
cat(str) #to output
# or message(str)
```

The `%i` are placeholders that expect integer values, see `?sprintf` for more details. Although this solution still relies on surrounding double quotes with single quotes, you get much more readable code than when using `paste` or `cat` directly.