# Send a text string containing double quotes to function

Tags: r, string-formatting, double-quotes, output

I'm having a problem with using double quotes while formatting text strings being sent to functions in R.

Consider an example function code:

```
foo <- function( numarg = 5, textarg = "** Default text **" ){ 
    print (textarg)
    val <- numarg^2 + numarg
    return(val) 
}
```

when running with the following input:

```
foo( 4, "Learning R is fun!" )
```

The output is:

```
[1] "Learning R is fun!"
[1] 20
```

But when I try (in various ways, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117321/solve-the-double-qoutes-within-double-quotes-issue-in-r)) to write "R" instead of R, I get the following outputs:

```
> foo( 4, "Learning R is fun!" )
[1] "Learning R is fun!"
[1] 20
> foo( 4, "Learning "R" is fun!" )
Error: unexpected symbol in "funfun( 4, "Learning "R"
> foo( 4, "Learning \"R\" is fun!" )
[1] "Learning \"R\" is fun!"
[1] 20
> foo( 4, 'Learning "R" is fun!' )
[1] "Learning \"R\" is fun!"
[1] 20
```

Using `as.character(...)` or `dQuote(...)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179091/how-to-print-variables-inside-quotes-in-message) seems to break the function because of different number of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these approaches:

```
foo <- function(numarg = 5, textarg = "** Default text **" ){ 
    cat(c(textarg, "\n")) 
    val <- (numarg^2) + numarg
    return(val) 
}

foo <- function(numarg = 5, textarg = "** Default text **" ){ 
    print(noquote(textarg)) 
    val <- (numarg^2) + numarg
    return(val) 
}

foo( 4, "Learning R is fun!" )
foo( 4, 'Learning "R" is fun!' )
```

Comment: Thanks! They both work! I've noticed I can use just `cat(textarg, "\n")` instead of formatting the output as an array by using `cat(c(textarg, "\n")`. Which is preferred?

Answer (score 5):

Two ways I know. First is to just use single quotes to start and end the character string:

```
> cat( 'Learning "R" is fun!' )
Learning "R" is fun!
```

Second is to escape the double quotes:

```
> cat( "Learning \"R\" is fun!" )
Learning "R" is fun!
```

Note that this works because I use `cat`, which is intended to output strings to the console. It seems you use `print()` which shows the object rather than output it

Comment: When I try to use `cat` while sending text to function, the text is formatted properly (using any of your suggestions), only this time, it outputs `Learning "R" is fun!NULL` instead of `Learning "R" is fun!`. Any idea how to terminate that `NULL` addition? (And even more importantly, any idea where did it come from?)